# Abstract Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to create an abstraction layer between Entity Framework and the rest of my application. But I am having a few problems with Entity Framework.

Basically (I don't show you all the interface layers that I've created too), I've split my application into several projects like this :

1. Domain

   - Contains my domain object, an abstraction of my datastorage object
2. DAL

   - Creates a link between my datastorage and my business layer. Contains two  types of elements :

     - Private ones : my EDMX, my database object, and some other generated objects providing me some useful methods like ToDomain/ToEntity
     - Public ones : my Data Access Object, providing CRUD methods
3. Business

   - Contains the logic of my application. Only knows about the public elements of the DAL and the Domain Layer.
4. Presentation

   - Presents the domain objects for the user. Only knows about the business layer.

As I said, I want to create an abstraction of my datastorage objects (in my case `Database` object, but I want a solution that works also for file or WCF storage for example) so that my business layer don't know anything about my DAL implementation.

Here is a glimpse of what I've done in my DAL :

```
public abstract class GenericDao<TEntity, TDomain, TDbContext> : IGenericDao<TDomain>
    where TDbContext : DbContext, new()
    where TEntity : class
    where TDomain : class
{
    protected TDbContext _context;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public GenericDao(TDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this._context = dbContext;
        this._dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public TDomain Create()
    {
        return this.ToDomain(this._dbSet.Create());
    } 

    public IList<TDomain> GetAll()
    {
        return this._dbSet.ToList().Select(entity => this.ToDomain(entity)).ToList();
    }

    public void Update(TDomain domain)
    {
        var entity = this.ToEntity(domain);

        var entry = this._context.Entry(entity);

        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Remove(TDomain domain)
    {
        _dbSet.Remove(this.ToEntity(domain));
    }

    protected abstract TDomain ToDomain(TEntity entity);

    protected abstract TEntity ToEntity(TDomain domain);
}
```

You will probably see what's wrong with my code by reading it: when I try to delete or update an entity, I am not manipulating an entity attached to Entity Framework. If I try to attach my entity to the `dbContext`, it fails because there is already an entity in the context with the same id.

I already thought about several solutions, but none of them please me.

Maybe am I doing something wrong in my approach? I am a little bit confused about the Repository and DAO pattern (I read anything and the very opposite about that difference on the internet).

Comment: *because there is already an entity in the context with the same id* - Why?

Comment: Firstly I retrieve an entity. It is stored into the dbContext. Then I return that entity to my business layer as new domain object (because I don't want my business layer knows anything about my data access layer). My business layer performs its work and then calls the update on my entity. Since the entry point of the update method is my domain object, I don't have any pointer to the entity object. And creating a new one causes the problem I get. With the Kirill Bestemyanov's second option, I can solve it, but I am not totaly satisfied with it. I'm still working on it. I will let you know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. initialize new `dbcontext` for each operation and dispose it when operation is ended:

   ```
   public abstract class GenericDao<TEntity, TDomain, TDbContext> : IGenericDao<TDomain>
   where TDbContext : DbContext, new()
   where TEntity : class
   where TDomain : class
   {
       protected Func<TDbContext> _contextFactory;

       public GenericDao(Func<TDbContext> contextFactory)
       {
           _contextFactory = contextFactory;
       }

       public TDomain Create()
       {
          using(var context = _contextFactory())
          {
              return context.Set<TEntity>().Create();
          }
       } 

       public IList<TDomain> GetAll()
       {
          using(var context = _contextFactory())
          {
             return context.Set<TEntity>().ToList()
                    .Select(entity => this.ToDomain(entity)).ToList();
          }
       }

       public void Update(TDomain domain)
       {
          using(var context = _contextFactory())
          {
             var entity = this.ToEntity(domain);
             context.Attach(entity);
             var entry = this._context.Entry(entity);
             entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
             context.SaveChanges();
          }
      }

      public void Remove(TDomain domain)
      {
         using(var context = _contextFactory())
         {
           var entity = this.ToEntity(domain);
           context.Attach(entity);
           context.Set<TEntity>.Remove(entity);
           context.SaveChanges();
        }
      }

      protected abstract TDomain ToDomain(TEntity entity);

      protected abstract TEntity ToEntity(TDomain domain);
   }
   ```
2. or you can try to find entity in your instance of `dbcontext` using property `Local` of `DbSet`:

   ```
   var contextEntity = context.Set<TEntity>().Local
       .Where(c=>c.Id == entity.Id).FirstOrDefault();
   ```

Comment: I'm working on a solution with your 2nd option. I didn't know that DbSet property, thank you. I'm not fully satisfied with it until now but I prefer it rather than your first solution. Is that even recommended ? I mean, instantiate a new dbContext for each call to my DAL (Currently, I have a per request dbContext) ? I will post my workaround soon so we could eventually improve it ^^.

Comment: it is not very rare to instantiate dbcontext for each call to DAL. It is typical in disconnected scenarios such as web sites and webservices.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting stuck coding to an implementation within your abstraction. If you injected an interface to your generic rather than a concrete type (like EF) then your GenericDao becomes much more flexible. You can inject whatever implementation you choose providing it implements the required interface. In your case, WCF, File, Whatever. For example;

```
protected IDbContext _context;

public GenericDao(IDbContext dbContext)
{
    this._context = dbContext;
}

public void Remove(TDomain domain)
{
    _context.Remove(this.ToEntity(domain));
}

//abstraction
public interface IDbContext
{
    void Remove(Entity entity);
}


//EF Implementation
public MyEfClass : IDbContext
{
    public void Remove(Entity entity)
    {
        //code to remove for EF example
        context.Attach(entity);
        context.State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.Set<TEntity>.Remove(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}

//WCF Implementation
public MyWCFClass : IDbContext
{
    public void Remove(Entity entity)
    {
        //Wcf implementation here
    }

}

//File example 
public FileWriter : IDbContext
{
    public void Remove(Entity entity)
    {
        LoadFile();
        FindEntry(entity);
        WriteFile(entity);
        SaveFile();
    }
    public void LoadFile()
    {
          //use app settings for file directory
    }

}
```

Comment: *You can inject whatever implementation you choose* I don't believe you. `IQueryable` is such a [leaky abstraction](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/) that you can't even make two implementations for two ORMs do the same thing, let alone completely different storage systems. The caller *always* has to be aware of the underlying implementation, which defeats the purpose of the abstraction.